# Samba - Apache Permissions

Tags: linux, apache, samba

I have a workflow set up with a linux centos server and 2 windows machines for web development.

Share files with samba in \ home \ client \ public_html \ cgi-bin

Every time I modify a file from windows I must make a chmod 755 on the modified file

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding
`force create mode = 0755`
to /etc/samba/smb.conf

will make all files created using samba have 0755 mask set.

Alternatively, you can use

`inherit permissions = yes`

Which will make all created files inherit the permissions of their parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you:

1. Install visual studio code with the SFTP plugin (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp).
2. Install FTP on the server (https://jealetecnologia.wordpress.com/2017/04/20/instalar-y-configurar-vsftpd-en-centos-7/)
3. Link Visual studio code with the server (https://artisansweb.net/ftp-sftp-extension-for-visual-studio-code/).

With this, only saving will be changed on the server and you will not have any problems with persmissions. No need to share folders in samba.